# How to Update Salesforce Objects from SOAP API or Server-Side JavaScript in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, soap-api

Following the importing of a flat file from the ExactTarget FTP on step one in an automation, on step two of the automation, we are using a server-side javascript activity to update Salesforce Objects using that data.  We know that AMPScript has a few built-in functions to work with salesforce objects.  Still, we want focus on SOAP API or Server-side JavaScript handling this request.

What function(s) in the server-side javascript library are able to update a Salesforce CRM object?

If there are no functions in server-side javascript yet that can work with Salesforce CRM objects, can server-side javascript call the UpdateSalesforceObject function in AMPScript directly? Or alternatively, can server-side javascript call a method of the Salesforce Connector API?

Our goal is to use a server-side javascript activity to directly update a Salesforce object.

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Have you been through this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/using-javascript-with-force-com.html)?

Comment: Hi Michael, could you tell me how to resolves this point with SSJ? I`m now reseaching on it too.

Comment: Someone did a proof of concept with using a landing page that is coded with the necessary ampscript functions to update salesforce objects and this landing page was called into the SSJS activity thereby executing the AMPScript code.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you try something like [this?](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/#UpdateSingleSalesforceObject):

```
%%[
var @result
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead","00300003yAEj","Email","jcc@example.com")
]%%
```